# Do sportspersons wear a "dress" or a "uniform"? What do you call the set of clothes that sports teams wear?

Tags: vocabulary

We usually talk about the jersey of a player but I am curious what's the overall attire of a player called - a **dress** or a **uniform**.

I am curious because **dress** usually refers to the female clothing and **uniform** has a military/police connotation and appears odd to me in context of sports.

Comment: jersey of a player? That is only the shirt, not the whole outfit. It can be uniform, if on a team yes. Meaning: the top shirt and the shorts or bottoms. The players were **dressed** in their team uniforms.

Comment: I don't know about other sports, but in (Association) football it's sometimes called _strip_ (at least in the UK). _Dress_ used to be used in the sense of _clothing, attire_ for either sex, but because of the feminine garment it is now only used of men's clothing in certain expressions (e.g. dress suit, ceremonial dress).

Comment: One might perhaps answer distinguishing between 'dress' (non-count noun), 'clothes of a particular style' and 'dress' (count noun), 'a piece of clothing for a woman that covers the top of the body and part or all of the legs'. But one will not, because a dictionary will provide that.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, football players (also rugby, hockey etc) wear a *kit* or a *strip*.

In cricket, the players traditionally don't wear a kit, but both teams dress alike, in white flannels.

> The Chelsea players are dressed in the new 2021 kit.

"Uniform" would not be used, except as a deliberate Americanism.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, "uniform" is the most common word. It does not necessarily carry a military/police connotation. (Even an employee can be said to wear his or her company's uniform.)

Here, for example, is a website dedicated to sports uniforms, and it's called "Uni Watch": https://uni-watch.com/. (By the way, the abbreviation "uni" is occasionally used in AE, but not often.)

Comment: "the abbreviation "uni" is occasionally used in AE"  I wish it were not used in BrE.

Comment: uni in BrE means university.